# How does a 6 channel color correction matrix work?

Tags: image-processing, colors, color-mapping, colormatrix, color-management

I would like to know how to implement a colour correction algorithm. Specifically, I want to simulate the color correction sliders of a JVC projector in my own code for a custom calibration program.

The projector has the sliders "Axis Position", "Hue", "Saturation" and "Brightness" for the colours red, green, blue, yellow, cyan and magenta. See the [JVC website](https://manual3.jvckenwood.com/projector/mobile/dla/b5a-1144-06en/BONDSYrhrdpkhl.php) for reference. But how do they work? Is it applied to RGB, XYZ or HSB colorspace?

In the past I have done the code for XYZ to XYZ correction with a 3x3 matrx, but that does not seem to fit in this case.

Another idea was to convert the color to HSB and change the hue, saturation and brightness, but how to deal with the axis?